# Setting dynamic text field to a certain number of characters

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, input

How can I set to filling out a form dynamic text field entered the specified number of characters no less and no more, eg 12.

maxlength = "12" limits the number to 12 but up.

The following script code, which I would in this way secure. Can this be done directly in php and not in JavaScript-because you can turn it off?

```
<script src="js/addInput.js" language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="dynamicInput">Serial No<b><font color="#FF0000">*</font></b> 
1: <input type="text" name="myInputs[]" maxlength="12" > np 6544/2014-01 
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add number" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

kod pliku js/addInput.js

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 20;
function addInput(divName){
  if (counter == limit) {
    alert("Add only 20 numbers");
  }
  else {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = "Serial number<font color='#FF0000'>*</font> " + (counter + 1) + ": <input type='text' maxlength='12' name='myInputs[]'>";
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use maxlength in input

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="20">
```

Answer (score 0):

To limit your inputs from 12 to 12, try this

```
<input type='text' pattern=".{12,12}" maxlength="12" name='myInputs[]'/>
```

About the limit, you should control it in php, something like:

```
if( count($_POST['myInputs']) > 20){
     //error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bad idea to avoid JS in browser just because someone can turn it off:

- 1. a page will lose a lot of dynamic and interactive stuff (I think it's pointless nowadays)
- 2. client browser can do all the dirty work instead of server
- 3. even if JS is disabled, a user can manually send GET-request with bad-formatted parameters to the server
- 4. a common practice achieving good results is make in browser beatiful responsive design using JS (prevent input of wrong data by handling user activity) and on server re-verify some of request parameters (that are critically sensitive to some format)

So try this in browser:

```
  <script>
    var input = document.getElementById( 'myFormId' )['exactInput']
        , lastCorrectValue = ''
        , neededSize = 12

    input.addEventListener( 'change', function ( e )
    {
      if ( e.target.value.length !== neededSize )
      {
        e.target.value = lastCorrectValue       
      }
      else
      {
        lastCorrectValue = e.target.value        
      }
    } )
  </script>
</body>
```

When the input losing focus it discards changes if new data has wrong length.

The `'change'` event can be buggy in old browsers, so you can also use the `'blur'` event same way.

Comment: by the way, the op said: `Can this be done directly in php and not in JavaScript-because you can turn it off?`